# What is the correct way of having multiple ActionListeners in a class in Java?

Tags: java

I am still a beginner in Java and would like to check if the way i code is correct. My question is about having multiple ActionListeners in a class that control som objects.

I have 2 menus and buttons and these 3 have actionlisteners to listen to what i am giving as input.

For the buttons, i use the actionlistener method that is auto generated via "`implements Actionlistener`"

For the two menus i just use

```
menu1.addActionListener(new ActionListener)
{Auto generated code}
```

Is this efficient enough or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Please post your code. Without code, your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

When the code that you want to execute after a button action differs from button to button, your method of implementation is correct.

If, however the actions you want to execute are similar to each other and could be handled by one single listener in a more concise way, you might assign the same `ActionListener` to multiple buttons.
One way of doing this is by implementing the `ActionListener` interface in the class where you declare / initialize the buttons, and then registering it by calling `menu1.addActionListener(this);`.

Comment: `"One way of doing this is by implementing the ActionListener interface in the class where you declare / initialize the buttons"` -- which may be OK for small "toy" programs but is not something generally worth recommending as it gives the "view" class too much responsibility (remember -- one main responsibility per class), making it harder to debug/enhance/alter.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use the `javax.swing.Action` abstraction. In its `actionPerformed()` method implement what you want the menu item to do (with MVC separation, that should be a thin wrapper calling some controller method).

Then, just do `menu.add(action);`.

Action implements ActionListener, and the advantage is that the action contains not only the implementation, but also its name, an icon, a keyboard shortcut etc. And you can use it to create menu items, dialog buttons, toolbar buttons and so on, as all these Swing elements know how to initialize themselves from an Action.

```
private Icon deleteIcon = ...;
private Action deleteAction = new AbstractAction("Delete", deleteIcon) {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        // do whatever you want, typically ignoring the event.
    }
};

//...

private void initializeGui() {
    // in a main menu:
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(fileMenu);
    fileMenu.add(deleteAction);

    // or as a button:
    add(new JButton(deleteAction), ...);
}
```

Comment: Sounds interesting. Could you show this in a sample code?

Comment: OK, I'll add an example.